# WebView - get back to Facebook comment when login successful

Tags: android, android-webview, facebook-comments

I'm developing a travel application. It has many place and user can comment on it using facebook comments.
I used a WebView to display facebook comments. It can show the comments. 
[image]

But when click login and login successfully, the webview stand at that page and don't come back to Comment box.
[image]

How to make WebView get back to comment box page or get something callback when login successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you get a link back, when the page has finished loading. This link allows you to check and then trigger an action.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewAuth);
String url = "<Facebook auth url>";
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.getUrl();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, it work. I can get refback by view.getUrl() then handle the WebView

Comment: Hello. Dolphin, can I see your .html-file with javascript for Comments box? Thanks.